# Formatting a string containing a number separated by comma in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, nsnumberformatter

I have one double value. I have to display a double value separated by a commas in a UILabel. But instead of commas i got dot. Here is my code.

```
double totalCost = [abcCost doubleValue] + [defCost doubleValue];
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
numberFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];// this ensures the right separator behaviour

numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
numberFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;
NSNumber *totalCostNum = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:totalCost];
NSString *totCostStr = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:totalCostNum];
NSLog(@"%@", totCostStr);//123,345.46 prints
costLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %@", totCostStr];
```

while display that value in UILabel it shows 123.345.46. I want to display the value in this format 123,345.46.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a bit bizarre, having groups of 2 and 3 digits like that.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is correct. I had done a small mistake. UILabel height is small, that's why it seems to be a dot. When i increased the height it displays comma.